# SQLPLUS set defaults for pagesize and linesize

Tags: sqlplus

When I start a session I can set the pagesize and linesize with the corresponding set command + desired value. How can I make it so that this value sticks upon launch of a new session?

Answer (score 0):

Open glogin.sql with notepad and add the following lines at the bottom: (including --- without "quotes") then save.

SET LINESIZE 200
SET PAGESIZE 1000

"---"